# What is the correct Lewis structure for calcium phosphate?

Tags: ionic-compounds, lewis-structure

In calcium phosphate, $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$, since the calcium and phosphate share an ionic bond, and the phosphorus and oxygen share a covalent bond, should the Lewis structure be like the following?

[image: ionic Lewis structure]

While I was checking other web pages I noticed there was another Lewis structure for the same molecule:

[image: Lewis structure with covalent bonds between phosphate and calcium]

Are they both possible Lewis structures, or is the first structure the only "correct" version of the molecule?

Comment: The first one is definitely more realistic.

Comment: Note that calcium phosphate is ionic, not covalent.

Answer (score 6):

Calcium phosphate crystallises in a number of different modifications of which β-$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ is the stable room temperature and ambient pressure modification. It has a rather complex structure not easily described, consisting of chains and rings with phosphate and calcium ions in specific patterns. It is orthorhombic, but $c \gg b \approx a$.

Any attempt to simplify its structure by drawing it in pseudocovalent depictions like your lower scheme is doomed to fail. Better just use the upper scheme; unless you are expected to know a certain salt’s crystal structure that one is safe.

Comment: Just for reference: M. Yashima *et. al*, *J. Solid State Chem.* **2003,** *175* (2), 272-277. DOI: [10.1016/S0022-4596(03)00279-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4596(03)00279-2). Unfortunately no ESI, and no deposition in ccdc.